# Draw an arrow at a specifict point on a circle using tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

In the below file, how I can easily put a little arrow at the point `i`, like in the below image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O};
\tkzDrawCircle[R](O, 1cm); %draw circle 1 centered at O with radius 1
\tkzDefPoint(90:1){i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `decoration`  library

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings,
            mark=at position .25 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}};}]
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O};
        \tkzDrawCircle[R,postaction={decorate}](O, 1cm); %draw circle 1 centered at O with radius 1
        \tkzDefPoint(90:1){i};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the question. What is the magic number `.25`? What if one would like to another position, e.g., at angle 30 degree.

Comment: `.25` of end of your path in this case a circle

Comment: `30` degree <=> `1/12`